# JODConverter & Open Office - Additional Export Options

Tags: jodconverter

I was wondering if anyone knew how to add additional export options when converting from a Word document to a PDF using JODConvertor 3 & Open Office.

What we want to achieve is to stop users being able to click check-boxes after the conversion has taken place.

I found the following document containing what looks like what I need, but I am currently using the conversion library from the command line.

http://www.artofsolving.com/node/18

It would appear that I need to add the "Changes" options to "0".  Is this done in the "document-formats.js" file?

Any help if greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution? I'm having the same issue ..

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by downloading the source of jodconverter  and editing the DefaultDocumentFormatRegistry class. After this I compiled it to JAR and added it to my webservice project.